# How to get a string of directory which contains single backslash in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get a directory argument from cli using node js.
Suppose my command line is: node myapp.js D:\test\strange.
when I do
console.log(process.argv[2])
it shows:
D:teststrange
how do I get D:\test\strange

Comment: Try like this: `node.js D:/test/strange`

Comment: If you're trying to specify a string IN nodejs to have backslashes in it, then you need to double them up: `const dir = "D:\\test\\strange"`.

Comment: The backslash is an escape character. Which operating system and which terminal are you using for your cli?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is in the command line processor of the shell used to run node.   Using

```
console.log(process.argv)
```

as the contents of `log-argv.js`,

1. Under the Windows command line processor `CMD.exe`

   ```
    node log-argv D:\test\strange
   ```

   outputs (in test directory `D:\localhost\SO`)

   ```
    [
      'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
      'D:\\localhost\\SO\\log-argv',
      'D:\\test\\strange'
    ]
   ```

   which is what was wanted.
2. Under `git-bash.exe` for windows however, the same command line outputs

   ```
    [
      'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
      'D:\\localhost\\SO\\log-argv',
      '\x96D:teststrange'
    ]
   ```

   suggesting node is relying on the command line processor, used to run it, to parse the command line string for it. This is entirely consistent with C programming practice.

---

Recall that Windows equally accepts forward or back slashes as directory delimiters in file path strings. Depending on the circumstances under which the issue arise, you should be able to type or generate command line file paths using forward slash delimiters, as commented by @GillesQuenot.